# Why my images and texts isn't being scaled on different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to support different screen sizes as shown on guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts.

I have 5 different drawable folders:

- drawable(image size 40x48png)
- drawable-mdpi(image size 80x96png)
- drawable-hdpi(image size 120x144png)
- drawable-xhdpi(image size 160x192png)
- drawable-xxhdpi(image size 210x252png)

My project includes 5 different layout folders for each size:
300dp, 330dp, 480dp, 600dp, 720dp. Every folder has the same layout.xml file.

My layout code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:text="Truuuuu"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.39"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/off50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/off50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/akcija"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pewpew!"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/off50"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/off50"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/off50"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="pewpew"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/idk"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is.. I do have different image folders and image files right? I made layout folders as well. My text isn't scaling either, on layout-sw720dp, for example, I can almost read the text.

What should I do to support text scaling? Why the image isn't being scaled on different screen sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you're confused.

If you have the same layout file in each sw folder-  don't.  You only write a new layout file if you have different screen layouts for that size.  Note that means entirely new or deleted elements, or changed positions.  If you're just changing values, you use values files.

Remember that page you linked, while a good resource, mentions multiple things you can do.  You're not supposed to do all of them, in fact some of them are contradictory.  The right thing to do depends on how you want things to look.

For your image scaling-  you're scaling based on screen density.  That means all devices with the same density will use the same drawable, which will make it look the same physical size, but not scale relative tot he size of the device.  That may or may not be what you want.  If it isn't, you probably want to define a fixed size in dp of the image or make it match_parent and use a scaleType to scale it.

For text size-  you're putting a fixed text size of 20sp everywhere.  That will make it the same height on all devices.  Generally making text bigger on different screen sizes isn't done much.  If you want it, make the 20sp a dimension and set different values for it in dimen.xml files based on the size.

Helping you more than this really requires more info-  what is it you're trying to achieve and what is it you're getting.

Comment: I got the point about the values part. Should I use the same numbers I did while creating layout folders(sw)?  I changed my image characteristic to (width and height 150dp, centerCrop scaleType and the image still cant be scaled.. hmm

Comment: Yes.  Those numbers seemed fairly sane to me.  They're all a bit arbitrary of course.  I'd say maybe 300 vs 330 dp isn't too important.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to fix text, now I'm only left with images.. playing around to get the point of it.. Still can't :/

Comment: Hey @Gabe Sechan,  I have changed my width and height to 150dp and I already tried different scaleTypes.. maybe Im doing something wrong within my folders?

Comment: So setting a 150 dp size means the view will always be 150 dp -  always about .9 inches square, and the image will scale within it baed on scaleType.  If you want some other effect (say wanting it to take all the space before some element, or to always take 10% of the screen) you need to use other techniques

Comment: Do I need to declare something in a manifest to make the scale type work?